# ¿Cómo puedo poner al revés el orden de la cadena dada en el parámetro?

Tags: javascript

Sé que tengo que usar .reverse(); y me imagino que también lo primero que tengo que hacer es pasar a un array la cadena dada en el parámetro pero no se de que manera podría hacerlo ni en que orden. Les dejo mi código a continuación.

```
function reverseString(str) {
  return str;
}

reverseString("hello");
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

(Lo que quiero es que si pongo "hello" como parámetro al momento de regresar el valor diga "olleh").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este es un método para realizar lo que deseas:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  return str.split("").reverse().join("");;
}

alert(reverseString("hello"));
```

Te escribo un método ya que en realidad existen distintas formas de realizar esto, te recomiendo este artículo, donde podrás encontrar 10 formas de realizarlo, realizado por [Edd Mann](https://github.com/eddmann):
http://eddmann.com/posts/ten-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript/

1: Decrementando for-loop con concatenation

```js
function reverse(s) {
  var o = '';
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += s[i];
  return o;
}

alert(reverse("hello"));
```

```
...
...
...
```

10:

```js
function reverse(s) {
  if (s.length < 2)
    return s;
  var halfIndex = Math.ceil(s.length / 2);
  return reverse(s.substr(halfIndex)) + reverse(s.substr(0, halfIndex));
}

alert(reverse("hello"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte, saludos!.